# How do you start a Selenium in Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, raspberry-pi, selenium-chromedriver

How to set up a Selenium in Google or Chrome?

I have tried both to no success.

It will be on raspberry pi model b v1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you will need to install ChromeDriver which you can get from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/). After that you need to install the selenium library with `pip install selenium`. To start it just do

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver') # Optional arg (will search current directory if not supplied)
driver.get('http://www.google.com/');
```

Comment: Yeah, have done that:

I have a while true loop in my code that runs code, waits a set amount of time, and then loops it again. On the second time round i always get this error:

```Exception has occurred: MaxRetryError
HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=65216): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/2f594c29cf83c6b4d367bb43277ac0f6/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000002B665C049D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))```

Comment: Are you able to visit that link manually in your browser? It could be that the server is not running

Answer (score 0):

Hello that is a very easy question to search in youtube there, there are a lot of videos to explain that properly then ( for example how to create chrome PATH)

I think this video is a good point to start
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xjv1sY630Uc

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

put the chromedriver in the same directory with the python script

then write:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.google.com/')
```